# C++ Binary File to Structure Function

Tags: c++

I have a struct:

```
    struct zipType{
    int postalCode;
    double longitude;
    double latitude;  
    };
```

And I have a function called zipToCout:

```
    void zipToCout(zipType zip){
    cout << "Postal Code = " << zip.postalCode << "\tLongitude = " << zip.longitude << "\t\tLatitude = " << zip.latitude << endl;
    }
```

now I need a function to read a binary file into a zipType struct. The function prototype is supposed to be `void binRead(zipType *zip, fstream *input);`. The only way I can get close to this is by changing the prototype to this `void binRead(zipType &zip, fstream &input)`. With that, Here is what I currently have for the function:

```
    void binRead(zipType &zip, fstream &input){
    int temp;
    double temp2;
    zipType tempZip;
    tempZip = zip;
    //cout << "Reader at location " << input.tellg() << endl;
    input.read((char*)&temp,sizeof(int));
    tempZip.postalCode=temp;
    input.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(double));
    tempZip.longitude=temp2;
    input.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(double));
    tempZip.latitude=temp2;
    zipToCout(tempZip);
    }
```

This is the output I get when I run this on my sample.bin file:

```
    Postal Code = 64501     Longitude = 2.61457e-261                Latitude = -7.13357e+288
```

What I need help with is reformatting the function to use `*`'s  instead of `&`'s and fixing how to read the file into the three variables correctly. Thanks for looking! Also, I only have to read one zipType from the file at this point.

Comment: When you used `zipType*` did you also use `->` instead of `.` to access the structure members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void binRead(zipType *zip, fstream *input)
{
    input->read((char*)( &zip->postalCode ),  sizeof(int   ));
    input->read((char*)( &zip->longitude  ),  sizeof(double));
    input->read((char*)( &zip->latitude   ),  sizeof(double));
    zipToCout(*zip);
}
```

Also, depending on the architecture (ie. 32-bit x86), the following *may* work:

```
void binRead(zipType *zip, fstream *input)
{
    input->read((char*) zip, sizeof(zipType));
    zipToCout(*zip);
}
```

That will only work on architectures where `double` only requires 4-byte alignment.  I believe 32-bit x86 fits that.  A quick test I wrote locally suggests that's the case.

A quick note on portable, maintainable code that goes beyond the immediate need above:  Code such as the above works well enough when the machine saving the data is the same as the machine that later reads the data.  It does, however, result in portability problems.  If you really want to design a file format that's portable across machines and preserves data, the above techniques aren't really conducive to that.

Comment: That works amazing. I almost had that earlier but couldn't figure out the syntax, I was trying `input.->read` for some reason. Cheers man! I still have the printout `Longitude = 2.61457e-261                Latitude = -7.13357e+288`. Is that normal?

Comment: Those do seem like bogus coordinates.  But, it at least is no change from what you had before.  How big is your input .bin file?  If it's 24 bytes, then you probably need to eat 4 bytes of pad somehow between your `int` and your `double` variables.  (Not hard to do.)  If it's only 20 bytes, then I'm not sure what the problem might be.

Comment: Also, I would be interested in what you have to say about the portability issues that could be caused, I'm all about coding in the best way possible.

Comment: I'd say it has more than one record in it though, as my next task is to read the entire file.

Comment: 216 bytes is 9*24, which hints the original structure is 24 bytes.  To read this properly, you need to add either an `input->read` that consumes 4 bytes into a dummy variable, or that seeks 4 bytes ahead between reading `postalCode` and `longitude`.  As far as portability goes, it's not a topic that's easily summed up in a SO comment.  But to a first order: byte order, field alignment, and data representation in general are all very machine specific, and you'd do well to isolate machine representation from the "on the wire" format.  You might look at Google Protocol Buffers for one example.

Comment: Joe does the last comments means that you have to take care of padding in each new line read? Also, from where does this figure of 4 bytes came?

Comment: Just to let you know, i used `input->seekg(8);` after the `postalCode` and that fixed it, I'll have to do a little modification when I do the whole file, but it gives me something to start with. Thank you very much!

Comment: You probably want `seekg(4, ios_base::cur)` so you skip exactly 4 bytes.  The issue:  `int` is 4 bytes, but `double` is 8 bytes.  On some architectures, `double` must be on an 8 byte boundary, but on 32-bit x86, `double` only needs to be on a 4 byte boundary.  On machines where `double` needs to be on an 8 byte boundary, a `struct` with `int; double; double;` will have 4 bytes of pad between the `int` and the first `double` and a minimum alignment constraint of 8 bytes, so that the `double` is 8-byte aligned.  On 32-bit x86, it won't have that padding because it doesn't require the alignment.

Comment: The case that you are mentioning will that really gonna affect us since our language takes cares of off this ion a form of abstraction.
Doesn't matter whether our architecture is making double at 4byte boundary or 8 byte boundary. I think this architecture thing is abstracted from the user unless you are doing some bit level operations.
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: In this code, it's not abstracted at all.  The binary input file has a particular byte order, and a particular packing of fields.  It has 9 records of 24 bytes, and so was likely generated on a machine where doubles were forced to 8 byte boundaries.  But, the code reading it doesn't necessarily enforce that same boundary.  These abstractions leak the moment the machine that writes the data is different than the machine that reads the data.  (And, to be clear, 32-bit code and 64-bit code on the same processor are effectively different "machines" for the sake of this argument.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in while printing the values.
if you see the value is read in string and printed as other datatypes. I guess proper conversion function should work for you. and use see my comments below.

```
void binRead(zipType &zip, fstream &input){
    char* temp = NULL
    char* temp2 = NULL;
    zipType tempZip;
    tempZip = zip; 
    //cout << "Reader at location " << input.tellg() << endl;
    input.read(temp,sizeof(int));
    tempZip.postalCode=(atoi)temp; //use for proper conversion, or other function
    input.read(temp2,sizeof(double));
    tempZip.longitude=static_cast<double*>temp2; //use for proper conversion, or other function
    input.read(temp2,sizeof(double));
    tempZip.latitude=static_cast<double*>temp2; 
    zipToCout(tempZip);
    }
```

Few comments on above code,

```
tempZip = zip; //why this, since you havn't declared any proper assignment 
operator. Use memcpy instead.
```

`tempZip.postalCode=(atoi)temp; //use for proper conversion, or other function`

```
tempZip.longitude=static_cast<double*>temp2; //use for proper conversion, or other function
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: Give me a bit I'll test this and get back to you, Thanks a lot for the quick help!

Comment: This works perfect as well, both answers given will do the trick, I needed to use `*` instead of `&` in the prototype so I used the first reply, but I do understand how to convert now which greatly helps. Thank you so much!

Comment: It only lets me choose one, and since I used the code from the first one, I chose that one. If there is a like button I'm missing let me know, because I definitely will, as your answer was also very helpful.

Comment: @BhupeshPant :  Your code doesn't set `temp` and `temp2` to point anywhere valid.  Your code may work if you're lucky, but it won't be robust.  In fact, I expect it to crash on most systems.  And this line is an abomination:  `input.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(double));`  You've taken the address of a `char *` and typecast _that_ address to `char *` also.  You're storing a `double` in a variable meant to hold a pointer.

Comment: No you are right I dont have any editor with me, just pointed out the scenario in a raw way. but you are right. Also please refer my first two lines of actual way..I will make the necessary changes

Comment: but user2990286 you can always rate up one. click on up arrow ... Thanks!

Comment: @JoeZ, I have made the necessary changes. Thanks again.. Its still a notepad code. :)